# Azure Hyperscale - How to reduce allocated space?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure Hyperscale db.
Db size is 2 GB
Allocated space is 4.7 GB

I am being charged by the allocated spcae of course....
DB SHRINK is not supported

What are my options to reduce the size ?
Will a db restore create a db sized 2 GB or 4.7 GB ?

db shrink did not help at all

Answer (score 2):

Not only DBCC SHRINKDATABASE is not supported. DBCC SHRINKFILE or setting AUTO_SHRINK to ON at the database level, aren't currently supported either for Hyperscale databases as stated on [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/service-tier-hyperscale?view=azuresql-db#known-limitations).

The only possible solution may be to create a new database and copy the data, for example, using Azure Data Factory.

Take in consideration, however, that on Hyperscale when the database is getting full the Hyperscale service grows them automatically in chunks of 10 GB.

Comment: Thank you @AlbertoMorillo, It's crazy that there is no AUTO_SHRINK for Hyperscale

Comment: It is complicated due to the storage architecture of the product.